# ffmpeg decode example using vda acceleration?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm testing the vda hw accelerated decoder of ffmpeg, but have no luck so far.

the command line I use is this:

```
./ffmpeg -hwaccel vda -i ~/Downloads/big_buck_bunny_720p_surround.avi -c:v rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p out.yuv
```

(the input video can be downloaded here: http://mirrorblender.top-ix.org/peach/bigbuckbunny_movies/big_buck_bunny_720p_surround.avi)

but it uses the sw decoder, instead of the requested vda hw decoder.

I debugged ffmpeg.c, and found out that in the function get_format:

```
if (!(desc->flags & AV_PIX_FMT_FLAG_HWACCEL))
    break;
```

the desc->flag isn't set with AV_PIX_FMT_FLAG_HWACCEL, so it skips the hw acceleration initialization.

the reason is because the pix_fmt is set to AV_PIX_FMT_NONE for some reason, instead of yuv420p as specified by the command.

I then changed the command to this:

```
./ffmpeg -hwaccel vda -i ~/Downloads/big_buck_bunny_720p_surround.avi -c:v rawvideo -pix_fmt vda_vld out.yuv
```

but what I got was:

```
Impossible to convert between the formats supported by the filter 'format' and the filter 'auto-inserted scaler 0'


Error opening filters!
```

Can you please show me an example of using ffmpeg to dump the above video into yuv using the vda hw decoder?

UPDATE from the ffmpeg mailist.

I was told to try the following command instead:

```
    ./ffmpeg -vcodec h264_vda -i ~/Downloads/big_buck_bunny_720p_surround.avi out.yuv
```

but this is what I got:

```
./ffmpeg -vcodec h264_vda -i ~/Downloads/big_buck_bunny_720p_surround.avi out.yuv

ffmpeg version 2.6.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
built with Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.57) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
configuration: 
libavutil      54. 20.100 / 54. 20.100
libavcodec     56. 26.100 / 56. 26.100
libavformat    56. 25.101 / 56. 25.101
libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
libavfilter     5. 11.102 /  5. 11.102
libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
[10:20:50.169] vtDecompressionDuctCreate signalled err=-8973 (err) (Could not select and open decoder instance) at /SourceCache/CoreMedia_frameworks/CoreMedia-1562.107/Sources/VideoToolbox/VTDecompressionSession.c line 1181
[h264_vda @ 0x7f9feb034600] Failed to init VDA decoder: -12473.
[avi @ 0x7f9feb00da00] Failed to open codec in av_find_stream_info
[NULL @ 0x7f9feb034600] missing picture in access unit with size 9960
[10:20:50.252] vtDecompressionDuctCreate signalled err=-8973 (err) (Could not select and open decoder instance) at /SourceCache/CoreMedia_frameworks/CoreMedia-1562.107/Sources/VideoToolbox/VTDecompressionSession.c line 1181
[h264_vda @ 0x7f9feb034600] Failed to init VDA decoder: -12473.
[NULL @ 0x7f9feb034600] missing picture in access unit with size 457
```

the reason I wanted to try this was because I wanted to use vda with libavcodec in the first place. but the problem I saw was exactly the above. looks like ffmpeg has the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cold emailed the author of `libavcodec/vda_h264_dec.c` who replied with the following message:

> I'm not very surprised that the VDA decoder cannot be properly inited
>   here. I guess you probably eventually have to remux your video to use
>   MP4 or MKV container.
>
> I don't know exactly what happens there, but according to my
>   experience playing with VDA framework before, that framework had quite
>   a few limitations. I guess the limitation you met might be that, it
>   required some extra data of the video to init the decoder, which made
>   it support only some of the containers. I forget what the exact name
>   of that extra data, but AFAIK, only MP4-compatible container could
>   provide that.

---

I also remember mp4 has an extradata field, but I don't know what it is.

I quickly tried the following command, it worked:

```
./ffmpeg -hwaccel vda -i ~/Downloads/big_buck_bunny.mp4 -c:v rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p out.yuv​
```